# Infusionsoft - How to get the all the available fields for a form using infusionsoft API (PHP SDK)

Tags: php, wordpress, api, infusionsoft

I am working on an infusionsoft application. I need to get all the available fields for a webform using infusionsoft API. I am doing continuous research on this issue, but cant find a solution for it. I need the available form fields to map to my current form. Should I need to hardcode the available form fields from infusionsoft. Is there any API call to achieve this, if so please give me the details of API call. I have checked dataservices but there is no documentation to retrieve the available form fields.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your only option:

http://help.infusionsoft.com/api-docs/webformservice#getHTML

It will give you the HTML for the webform if you have the webform ID. You will then have to parse all the HTML to get the exact fields.

Please see the sample request on the link I posted.

Comment: Updated URL: https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#webform